# how to add custom wp_nav_menu class css selector to ul and a tags?

Tags: menus

crafting a theme from finished html/css markup and wonder how to wrap `a` tags in my custom class?
With `ul` wrapper this is works:

```
            wp_nav_menu(
                array('menu' => 'menu-header',
                      'menu_class' => 'list',)
            );
```

but how to deal with menu items, and with currently selected menu item? 
I need `ul` to be with `.class` selector and `li` with `.item` selector as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example adds a unique CSS class to a single, specific nav menu item.

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {

    if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Blog' ) {
        $classes[] = 'special-class';
    }

    return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this is too trivial, all i was need it a filter on `nav_menu_css_class`